# How to create a Sort function that does not differentiate between String rule keys and Symbol rule keys

Tags: string-manipulation, functional-style, sorting, symbols, rule

Im trying to `Sort` `Rule`-s according to `Key`-s (or names) but the normal `Sort` routine places `String`-s above `Symbol`-s. My goal is to have them `Sort` equally by names.

Here is the normal `Sort` routine. Notice that it places `String` names above `Symbol`-s.

```
ClearSystemCache[];
ClearAll["Global`*"];

names = {c -> 3, d -> 4, "f" -> 6, g -> 7, "a" -> 1, e -> 6, h -> 8, 
   "b" -> 2};

Sort[names]

(* Out: {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "e" -> 6, "f" -> 6, c -> 3, d -> 4, g -> 7, 
 h -> 8} *)
```

Here are my two attempts at deriving a Sort function. Not good. No sorting occurs. Please help.

```
ClearSystemCache[];
ClearAll["Global`*"];

names = {c -> 3, d -> 4, "f" -> 6, g -> 7, "a" -> 1, "e" -> 6, h -> 8,
    "b" -> 2};

Sort[names, ToString[#1] < ToString[#2] &]

(* Out: {c -> 3, d -> 4, "f" -> 6, g -> 7, "a" -> 1, "e" -> 6, h -> 8, 
 "b" -> 2} *)

p[ToString[_x], ToString[_y]] /; x > y := -1;
p[ToString[_x], ToString[_y]] /; StringMatchQ[x, y] := 0;
p[ToString[_x], ToString[_y]] /; x < y := 1;
Sort[names, p]

(* Out: {c -> 3, d -> 4, "f" -> 6, g -> 7, "a" -> 1, "e" -> 6, h -> 8, 
 "b" -> 2} *)
```

Comment: I'd look at the `SortBy` function

Comment: `SortBy[names, ToExpression@Keys@# &]` ?

Comment: @mikado IT WORKED!!! here it is: `SortBy[names, ToString]` thank you. :)

Comment: @Syed i figured it out with a hint by mikado: `SortBy[names, ToString]` but thank you.

Comment: `"d"<"h" // TrueQ` does not evaluate it to `True`, it's not possible to compare strings with `<`  as can be checked in the Details section of [Less](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Less.html). If you want to use `Sort` you can use for example `Sort[names, Order @@ ToString /@ {#1, #2} &]`

Comment: By the way, related to a previous discussion, there is a question that recently appeared about dark style sheets [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/276551/86543) maybe you might be interested.