# Darker stylesheet for Notebook and overall Interface with high contrast for plots and graphics

Tags: stylesheet

I am currently looking for a stylesheet in a black theme that still has high contrast for graphics/plots and similar. Preferably it should also change the menu to a darker color. It preferably should also highlight the cells better.

I am working on computational physics problems that can sometimes take a lot of time and the white is quite painful after a bit but dark theme and dracula theme are simply not good for showing graphs. Sadly I do not know how to edit stylesheets but hopefully someone else already made one.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I should add that there are at least 2 init files, a kernel one and a front end one. I never modified the front end init file,  modifying the kernel one with the `SetOptions` commands below should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Outline**

- **Stylesheets**
- **Graphics visualization (`Plot`, `Graph`, `Dataset`, etc) modifications**
- **FrontEnd modifications**

---

### Stylesheets:

Consider perhaps the links below :

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/search/?i=stylesheet

I tried the dracula theme and indeed the contrast is not good for graphs. DarkMode in https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DarkMode/ looks better with graphs

(did not try this one)  https://github.com/search?q=mathematica+stylesheet

### Graphics visualization (`Plot`, `Graph`, `Dataset`, etc) modifications

#### For `Print`:

Use instead

```
print = Print[Style [#, White]] &
```

Or whatever color you like

#### For `Plot` and `Graphics`:

You can get the current background color with:

Note: `⎵=\[UnderBracket]`

```
background⎵color = 
  If[CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Background] === None, White, 
   CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Background]];
```

If you want optimal contrast you can choose the font color to be the opposite of that color:

```
print⎵color = ColorNegate@background⎵color;
```

Then you can modify the options of `Plot` and `Graphics`:

```
SetOptions[#, AxesStyle -> print⎵color, 
    Background -> background⎵color, 
    BaseStyle -> print⎵color] & /@ {Plot, Graphics};
```

**Note :** `BaseStyle` in `Plot` changes the default color of curves, consider changing that to whatever you prefer. You might also want to change it in `Graphics`.

**Note :** Consider including `ListPlot`, `ListLinePlot`, `ListLogPlot` etc to that list.

You might want to change some of the options. You can check:

```
Options[Plot]//Association //Dataset
```

for example to see the options of `Plot` and change them as you want. If you want to use your own visualization you can use

```
Options[Plot]
```

then use whatever you want like `Column` for example

#### For `DataSet`:

The functions to customize `Dataset` were introduced in version 12.1.

One option you can change is :

```
SetOptions[Dataset, 
  HeaderBackground -> background⎵color];
```

See `Options[Dataset]` for other options.

#### For `Graph`

If you generate a graph directly with `Graph` then you can use:

```
SetOptions[Graph, VertexLabelStyle -> print⎵color, 
 Background -> background⎵color, 
 BaseStyle -> print⎵color]
```

However that will not affect the options using other functions that output a `Graph` like `RandomGraph`. You might want to use the options above for each graph function considered.

#### How to make the changes permanent

If you want these option changes to `Plot` etc to be permanent then you might have to change your [init file](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html). It might be best to hardcode the color choice rather than using `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Background]` in the init file.

### FrontEnd modifications

To remove some of the bars that might be a different color than your style sheet see this answer:

**Note :** See also the comment for how to revert back

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101062/86543

If you use Linux you can change the color of the menu with:

[How to customise the appearance of the menubar and scrollbar on Linux?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/254038/86543)

My interface after slightly modifying [DarkMode](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DarkMode/) (linked in the stylesheet section) and changing the Qt file:

[image]

Not sure about my choice to use purple but it makes sense with my desktop theme.

I used this Qt configuration (I kept the popup menu for searching for files the same as I did not know how to control the colors well):

```
QScrollBar:vertical {
  background: black;
  width: 20px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
  background:  #03a9f4;
  min-height: 0px;
}
QMenu {
  background-color: #03a9f4; /* sets background of the menu */
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white
}

QMenu::item {
  /* sets background of menu item. set this to something non-transparent
        if you want menu color and menu item color to be different */
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white
}

QMenu::item:selected {
  /* when user selects item using mouse or keyboard */
  background-color: #bd15f4;
}

QMenuBar {
  background-color: black;
  spacing: 3px; /* spacing between menu bar items */
  color: white
}

QMenuBar::item {
  padding: 1px 4px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white
}

QMenuBar::item:selected {
  /* when selected using mouse or keyboard */
  background: #a8a8a8;
}

QMenuBar::item:pressed {
  background: #888888;
}


* { font-size:16pt; font-family:"Griffy" }
```

---

**Note:**

If you are willing to accept loosing a lot of the functionality of the front end of Mathematica consider also using Jupyter or VScode with the Wolfram Kernel and use a dark theme. See my answer here : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/274441/86543 for pictures of a dark theme with Jupyter and VScode